# Spring MVC in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.3

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am new to Java in IDEA especially in IntelliJ and Spring MVC. So this should be a very naive question to you, guys but it really troubled so much. I followed several tutorials to set up the first `hello, world` Spring MVC in IntelliJ but always failed including this [one](https://iamsaurabh.wordpress.com/2017/02/11/configure-a-spring-mvc-project-with-intellij-idea/), which is pretty good and quite recent (latest). I followed it completely using Spring instead of MVC and installed the latest **Tomcat** by following this [tutorial](https://wolfpaulus.com/mac/tomcat/), which is also pretty neat.

What I have done:

1. removed the problems caused by `"` double quotes in  the `dipatcher-sevlet.xml`;
2. tried to import the `tomcat` directly instead of using the `soft link`;

But still in the end, I cannot start the program only **Build** allowed. REALLY have no idea why I cannot just **RUN** it.

For now, I am trying to **create it** by **Maven** but still I am wondering what's going on here.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Thank you so much for your time.

Sincerely, Hearen

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot start the program only Build allowed"? Have you created new Tomcat Run/Debug configuration: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `base-package` in dispatcher-servlet.xml is correct and then `Run -> Edit Configuration -> + (top-left in the configuration page) -> Tomcat -> Local -> select the folder where tomcat installed.